# Validate presence of nested attributes within a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I have the following associations:

```
#models/contact.rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts_teams
  has_many :teams, through: :contacts

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts_teams, allow_destroy: true
end

#models/contacts_team.rb
class ContactsTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :team
end

#models/team.rb
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts_team
  has_many :contacts, through: :contacts_teams
end
```

**A `contact` should always have at least one associated team (which is specified in the rich join table of `contacts_teams`).**

If the user tried to create a contact without an associated team: a validation should be thrown.  If the user tries to remove all of a contact's associated teams: a validation should be thrown.

How do I do that?

I did look at the [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) docs.  I also looked at [this article](http://michaelwelburn.com/2014/02/10/rails-4-nested-object-creation-and-parent-presence-validation-error/) and [this article](http://homeonrails.com/2012/10/validating-nested-associations-in-rails/) which are both a bit dated.

For completion: I am using the `nested_form_fields` gem to dynamically add new associated teams to a contact.  Here is the relevant part on the form (which works, but currently not validating that at least one team was associated to the contact):

```
<%= f.nested_fields_for :contacts_teams do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.remove_nested_fields_link %>
  <%= ff.label :team_id %>
  <%= ff.collection_select(:team_id, Team.all, :id, :name) %>
<% end %>
<br>
<div><%= f.add_nested_fields_link :contacts_teams, "Add Team"%></div>
```

So when "Add Team" is not clicked then nothing gets passed through the params related to teams, so no `contacts_team` record gets created.  But when "Add Team" is clicked and a team is selected and form submitted, something like this gets passed through the params:

```
"contacts_teams_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"team_id"=>"1"}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does the validations for both creating and updating a `contact`: making sure there is at least one associated `contacts_team`.  There is a current edge case which leads to a poor user experience. [I posted that question here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36202273/edit).  For the most part though this does the trick.

```
#custom validation within models/contact.rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validate :at_least_one_contacts_team

  private
  def at_least_one_contacts_team
    # when creating a new contact: making sure at least one team exists
    return errors.add :base, "Must have at least one Team" unless contacts_teams.length > 0

    # when updating an existing contact: Making sure that at least one team would exist
    return errors.add :base, "Must have at least one Team" if contacts_teams.reject{|contacts_team| contacts_team._destroy == true}.empty?
  end           
end
```

Answer (score 6):

In Rails 5 this can be done using:

```
validates :contacts_teams, :presence => true
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Profile model nested in a User model, and you want to validate the nested model, you can write something like this: (you also need `validates_presence_of` because `validates_associated` doesn't validate the profile if the user doesn't have any associated profile)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
  validates_presence_of :profile
  validates_associated :profile
```

Answer (score 0):

docs recommend using reject_if and passing it a proc:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['title'].blank? }
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this works for this situation.  I am not validating on any attributes of the `contacts_team` record.  I only intend to validate that the `contact` has at least one associated `team`.  In other words: at least one associated `contacts_team` record.

Comment: pretty sure you can pass that proc any condition.

Comment: contact.teams.count > 0

Comment: When you create a new contact though it will not have any associated `contacts_teams` because both the `contacts_team` record has not yet been created.

Comment: you can't check to make sure the values are present in the params hash?

Answer (score 0):

Model Names:
1: approval
2: approval_sirs

Associations:
1: approval
has_many :approval_sirs, :foreign_key => 'approval_id', :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :approval_sirs, :allow_destroy => true
2: approval_sirs
belongs_to :approval , :foreign_key => 'approval_id'

In approvals.rb
    ## nested form validations
    validate :mandatory_field_of_demand_report_sirs

```
private

def mandatory_field_of_demand_report_sirs
    self.approval_sirs.each do |approval_sir|
        unless approval_sir.marked_for_destruction?
          errors.add(:base, "Demand Report Field are mandatory in SIRs' Detail") unless approval_sir.demand_report.present?
        end
    end
end
```