# Validating presence of nested attributes returns error "no method :path_base"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have a model which accepts nested attributes.  There are 4 attributes altogether and I need to verify the presence of one.  the specific attribute I need to verify for is called path_base so I tried

```
validates_presence_of :path_base
```

In the model but I am getting the error

```
undefined method `path_base' for #<Template:0x007fa279146360>
```

When saving the template record.  The params getting sent look like this

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZO+Pi3/6WwNk0H3cFhgDbRywjrAOv2RnZ7olIsenND0=", "already_saved"=>"false", "update_pages"=>"false", 
"template"=>{"type"=>"singleton", "name"=>"test", 
"template_responses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"path_base"=>"", "liquid_code"=>"test", "indexable"=>"1", "content_type"=>"text/html"}, "1"=>{"path_base"=>"", "liquid_code"=>"", "indexable"=>"1", "content_type"=>"text/html"}}, 
"template_fields_json"=>"[\r\n\r\n]"}, "button"=>""}
```

So inside the `template_responses_attributes` array is where the value of  `path_base` is, and that is inside the `template` array just like normal (template is the controller/model that is saving the record that accepts the nested attributes).

If anyone could point me in the correct direction for this it would be greatly appreciated.

I did try this, which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187666/validate-presence-of-nested-attributes-within-a-form) but it did not return an error when the value was empty.

```
reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['path_base'].blank? }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each model should only be responsible for validating its own attributes - if you want to ensure that the nested records are valid use [`validates_associated`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated).

```
class Template < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :responses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :responses

  # This validates all the associated records
  validates_associated :responses
end

class Response < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :path_base
  # ...
end
```

The `reject_if` option is not a validation mechanism. Rather it lets you filter out nested attributes if they do not meet a criteria, take for example a task list application where you would want to filter out the empty rows.